# OpenGL and MultiGPU

Tags: opengl, gpu, gpgpu

We are trying to setup a server with Multiple Tesla M2050 to run with OpenGL.

The current setup is as follows : Ubuntu 12.04 with NVidia Drivers. We have setup the xorg.conf with separate devices identified by BUS ID.

Now we have tied an X server each with display which in turn is tied to each device and our code is attached to each of these X servers. But somehow only one X session seems to work out alright. The other one produces garbled output and while watching it from nvidia-smi, we notice that when the garbled output is being produced the GPU's are not at all used.

Could someone verify that our setup seems reasonable? The other thing we noticed was that, it was only the first X server that was started is the one that has the issue.

EDIT : This is in headless mode.

Answer (score 3):

A problem with multiple X servers is, that each server may grab the active VT and hence disable the other X server's rendering output. This can be avoided. But I think in your situation good ole' *"Zaphod Mode"* would suit your needs far better:

Zaphod mode is a single X server, controlling multiple Devices, each with its own Monitor forming a Screen, joined in a single screen layout. *This is not TwinView or Xinerama!* In Zaphod mode you can not move windows between Screens, i.e. each Screen acts on its own.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, didn't mention that we need it in headless mode.

Comment: @Sumod: Headless is going to be a bit problematic, because as soon as the VT of the X server is attached to is deactivated, the X server will release the GPU its using so that other processes can take it over. In that case you'll have to do some trickery, so that multiple VTs stay active. This requires multiseat support from the Linux kernel *and* you must get rid of ConsoleKit as this will interfere in all kind of unsuitable ways. Unfortunately ConsoleKit has been integrated into systemd as of that is even harder to get rid off.

Comment: @Sumod: However if all you're after is, that the other GPUs will happily work along in parallel to a main GPU for the graphics output, well: Just don't connect monitors to them. Heck I bet you can configure them to have either no Monitor sections at all, or Screen sizes of 0x0 each. Of course you'll have to create PBuffer contexts or dummy window + FBO then, to get some visible output.